# Overflow hidden and clear:both removes paper effect shadow

Tags: html, css, shadow

I want to create a paper effect shadow using the following css, but I have 3 divs inside this a div which need to be side by side. I use float to make the divs side by side, but this makes the parent's div height smaller than the inner content. I tried clear:both and overflow: hidden to fix the issue which makes the height relative to the content but this removes the shadow effect.

**CSS**

```
.boxcontainer {
   position:relative;
   width:90%;
}

.boxcontainer:before,
.boxcontainer:after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   z-index:-1;
   bottom:15px;
   left:10px;
   width:50%;
   height:20%;
   max-width:300px;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
   transform:rotate(-3deg);
}

.boxcontainer:after{
   right:10px;
   left:auto;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
   transform:rotate(3deg);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="paperbox" class="boxcontainer">
    <img class="mafacemobile" src="/images/maface.jpeg" alt="ma face" width="183px" height="183px">
    <div id="textwrapper">
    <h1>
    FILLING MORE TEX
        </h1>
<div id="icons"
<img...>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no element in your code with `.drop-shadow` class?

Comment: Sorry I changed the classes name before posting here. I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't 100% sure of exactly what you had in mind for the end result due to the minimal code you provided, but hopefully this is close!

Check out my pen for a working model: http://codepen.io/gnowland/pen/crGtE

...and here's the finished code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="paperbox" class="boxcontainer">
  <div class="boxinner">
    <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://placehold.it/183x183" class="mafacemobile" alt="ma face" width="183px" height="183px">
    <div id="textwrapper">
      <h1>FILLING MORE TEXT</h1>
      <div id="icons"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://placehold.it/50"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.boxcontainer {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
}
.boxcontainer:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
  transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.boxcontainer:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
  transform:rotate(3deg);
}

.boxinner{
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
 }

.boxinner > * {
  /* NOTE: This is just for demo, utilize the exact selectors in your code */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px
 }
```

I used your `.boxcontainer` as a wrapper and added an inner div (`.boxinner`) to hold the contents so you can pad it, etc.

The major addition was using `display: inline-block`. Get friendly with that property, it's awesome.

You can play around with my code on codepen and let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

Hope this solved it for you! :-)

EDIT: I just realized your original question was from 7 months ago... you've probably figured it out already but hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:relative` to `.boxcontainer`

Could you provide the CSS for `.boxcontainer` and it's contents, too?
And also, which container is `.drop-shadow` being applied to?

It would be a good idea to set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. It's fixed now.